# How to have a correct display for hexadecimal packet?

Tags: c, uart

I am trying to make communication between laptop and UART, I want to display this packet: `ccddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233327224`
This is C code:

```
dev_uart_ptr = uart_get_dev(1);
uint8_t rx_buffer[38];
dev_uart_ptr->uart_open(230400, 1, 0);
memset(rx_buffer, 0, sizeof(rx_buffer));

while(1)
{
    int rx_length = dev_uart_ptr->uart_read(rx_buffer,38);
    if (rx_length <38)
    {
        printf("\rx_buffer \n",rx_buffer);
    }
    else
        for(i=0;i<10;i++);
}
```

The result is

```
x_buffer
x_buffer
x_buffe
r
x_buffer
x_buffer
x_buffer

x_buffer
x_buffer
x_buffer

x_buffer
x_buffer
x_buffer
x
_buffer
x_buffer
x_buffer
```

If I put

```
 while(1)
    {
        int rx_length = dev_uart_ptr->uart_read(rx_buffer,38);
        if (rx_length <38)
        {
            printf(rx_buffer);

        }
        else
            for(i=0;i<10;i++);
    }
```

the result that I have is:

```
eff8899aabb445566770011223327224cb┼▄  
 ccddeeff8899aabb445566770011223327224
cb┼▄   ccddeeff8899aabb445566770011223
327224cb┼▄   ccddeeff8899aabb445566770
011223327224cb┼▄   ccddeeff8899aabb445
566770011223327224cb┼▄   ccddeeff8899a
abb445566770011223327224cb┼▄1223332722
4cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb445566770011223
3327224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb445566770
0112233327224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb445
5667700112233327224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899a
abb4455667700112233327224cb┼▄   cddeef
f8899aabb4455667700112233327224cb┼▄   
cddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233327224c
b┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb44556677001122333
27224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb44556677001
12233327224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb44556
67700112233327224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aab
b4455667700112233327224cb┼▄   cddeeff8
899aabb4455667700112233327224cb┼▄   cd
deeff8899aabb4455667700112233327224cb┼
▄   cddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233327
224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb4455667700112
233327224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb4455667
700112233327224cb┼▄   cddeeff8899aabb4
455667700112233327224cb┼▄   cddeeff889
9aabb4455667700112233327224cb┼▄   cdde
```

At first, it works correctly, but now I don't know where is the problem. I would be very grateful if you could help me, please.

Comment: Do you know what the % character does in the first argument of `printf`?

Comment: rx_buffer 0x10007F2C ,, this is the result that i found after adding printf("rx_buffer 0x%02X\n",rx_buffer);

Comment: The bytes you receive are not null-terminated, see you can't print it like you are doing.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, do you think that the problem is in  the size of the buffer ?